# How to connect to a remote cluster in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

In Tensorflow 1.x, there was a way to connect an Estimator to a remote cluster using tf.contrib.distribute.DistributeConfig, as demonstrated by [this example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/blob/master/distribution_strategy/keras_model_to_estimator_client.py) in the Tensorflow ecosystem repository.

Tensorflow 2.0 introduced the experimental [MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy) and changed the implementation of `RunConfig` to use the `TF_CONFIG` environment variable for setting up the cluster. However, this requires the currently executing code to be part of that cluster, i.e. `task` must be set in `TF_CONFIG`. This of course doesn't make sense if you're trying to connect a client machine to a remote cluster.

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent way to achieve this in Tensorflow 2.0? I've been searching for hours, and the best I can come up with is connecting via a call to `tf.compat.v1.Session('grpc://[cluster-ip]:[cluster-port]')` and then setting things up using the `v1` compat APIs. This is less than ideal, since we are not only using the deprecated APIs but also seem to lose the ability to distribute across multiple workers (`Session` only connects to one node at a time).

Answer (score 0):

You can create `MultiWorkerMirroredStartegy` in the following way

```
multiworker_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
```

For this you also need to configure multi-worker setup using [TF_CONFIG](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/distributed-training-details#tensorflow-config) on different nodes.

```
TF_CONFIG='{"cluster": {"worker": ["worker1-IP:port", "worker2-IP:port"]}, "task": {"index": 0, "type": "worker"}}'
```

In this case the training code need to run individually on each node. You can also follow official tensorflow docs on [distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#setting_up_tf_config_environment_variable). If you are distributing the training across large number of nodes, consider using Kubernetes.